# Child component value not setting in Angular 2?

Tags: html, angular

So I have my child component's value marked like so:

```
@Input flag;
```

And then in the particular method I have:

```
myParentComponent.flag = true;
```

Then in the html of the parent component I have:

```
<app-childComponent-template [flag] = flag ></app-childComponent-template>
```

I'm using Chrome's inspection tool to watch the console where I'm logging the changes. When I set the flag to true in the child component it works, however, it won't carry over to the parent component and I can't figure out why. I've gone through this documentation (https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) multiple times but everything seems to match up accordingly.

Thank you!

Comment: By "carry over to the parent component" you mean that when you update the field in the child component, you want it reflected in the parent as well?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I tend to make up my own lingo to describe things at times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax `[flag]` indicates that it's a one-way data binding: The parent will push changes to `flag` to the child. But changing the child's `@Input flag` variable will not emit a change to the parent.

In order to do that, you need to use an `@Output` in the child component:

```
@Input('flag') flag;
@Output('flag') flagChanged = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

Then, to inform the parent that the flag has changed, emit an event from the child component:

```
this.flagChanged.emit(newFlagValue);
```

Finally, to be informed of changes in the parent component:

```
<app-childComponent-template [flag]="flag" (flag)="onFlagChanged($event)"></app-childComponent-template>

onFlagChanged(newValue) {
    alert(`New flag value: ${newValue}`);
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you! Do I stll need @Input at all then? I don't need the parent to push anything to child.

Comment: If you don't communicate from the parent to the child, you don't need an `@Input()` in the child.

Comment: @RainyAngel If you do end up providing `flag` to the child, but just want the child and parent's fields to be in sync, you can check out "two-way binding" - there is syntactic sugar for `[flag]="flag" (flag)="flag=$event"` which is referred to as "banana in a box" - See https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---