# Angular2 SyntaxError in Inspection Console

Tags: javascript, html, angular

So here is the error I'm getting in the webpage inspection console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.bundle.js:3885)
    at __webpack_require__ (polyfills.bundle.js:51)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (main.bundle.js:2268), <anonymous>:7:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.bundle.js:2268)
    at __webpack_require__ (polyfills.bundle.js:51)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (main.bundle.js:233), <anonymous>:17:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.bundle.js:233)
    at __webpack_require__ (polyfills.bundle.js:51)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (main.bundle.js:205), <anonymous>:4:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.bundle.js:205)
```

Now this literally tells me nothing in regards to the real error (except there's some kind of undefined/unknown token being used but I don't understand how or where).

I made the changed to my code according to a previous question I had (I followed exactly what the chosen answer said to do): [Child component value not setting in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51307942/child-component-value-not-setting-in-angular-2)

I know for a fact that @Output is causing the error but I can't for the life of me figure out why despite a good amount of debugging and research.

Visual Studio Code is not throwing any errors nor is my command prompt mentioning anything wrong with my files when it scans them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: 
So here is the code I find specifically triggers this problem in the child component:

```
@Output() flagChanged = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

The next lines are how it's being changed and interacting with the parent component.
Then I have this being called in a function below in the same child component:

```
this.flagChanged.emit(true);
```

Finally in the parent's html file I have this snippet of code that calls to store the value:

```
<app-onboard-cnp-template (flagChanged) = "onFlagChanged($event)"></app-onboard-cnp-template>
```

The error specifically underlines this line of code in a file I'm not touching at all:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
```

Comment: could you post a snippet of that code you modified you're talking about that you are suspecting to cause the issue?

Comment: I added the code pieces that are causing the problem specifically.

Comment: Add some stackblitz for your question it is very simple to answer for you.

Comment: Does this happen at compile time or run time? Try doing a production build - it might reveal your error at compile time since it does more exhaustive analysis/type checking. Also, what version of rxjs are you using? If you're using v6+, your import for Subject should just be `import {Subject} from 'rxjs';`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was painfully stupid but hopefully someone else will be able to solve it a lot faster than I did if they make the same mistake.

Solution: MAKE SURE TO IMPORT THE EVENTEMITTER FROM THE RIGHT MODULE.

```
import {EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
```

I was importing from a file that had "import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject'" in it which is why the token wasn't expected.